# A single instance of controller 'TestController' cannot be used to handle multiple requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container, lifetime

I have Some issues with the life time manager in unity, it uses the object like its singleton, but in the configuration I set it to "PerWebRequest".

The Error is:
A single instance of controller 'TestController' cannot be used to handle multiple requests. If a custom controller factory is in use, make sure that it creates a new instance of the controller for each request.

The PerWebRequest code:

```
public class UnityPerWebRequestLifetimeManager : LifetimeManager
{
    private HttpContextBase _httpContext;

    public UnityPerWebRequestLifetimeManager()
        : this(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
    {
    }

    public UnityPerWebRequestLifetimeManager(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    private IDictionary<UnityPerWebRequestLifetimeManager, object> BackingStore
    {
        get
        {
            _httpContext = (HttpContext.Current != null) ? new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current) : _httpContext;

            return UnityPerWebRequestLifetimeModule.GetInstances(_httpContext);
        }
    }

    private object Value
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get
        {
            IDictionary<UnityPerWebRequestLifetimeManager, object> backingStore = BackingStore;

            return backingStore.ContainsKey(this) ? backingStore[this] : null;
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            IDictionary<UnityPerWebRequestLifetimeManager, object> backingStore = BackingStore;

            if (backingStore.ContainsKey(this))
            {
                object oldValue = backingStore[this];

                if (!ReferenceEquals(value, oldValue))
                {
                    IDisposable disposable = oldValue as IDisposable;

                    if (disposable != null)
                    {
                        disposable.Dispose();
                    }

                    if (value == null)
                    {
                        backingStore.Remove(this);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        backingStore[this] = value;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    backingStore.Add(this, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        Value = newValue;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public override void RemoveValue()
    {
        Value = null;
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Test/

    public TestController()
    {

    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult RadioButtonList()
    {
        return View("TestControl");
    }
}
```

The Controller Factory:

```
public class ControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return (controllerType == null) ? base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType) : IoC.Resolve<IController>(controllerType);
    }
}
```

And in one of the views I am trying to use it like this:

...

```
<% Html.RenderAction<TestController>(c => c.RadioButtonList()); %>

                        <% Html.RenderAction<TestController>(c => c.RadioButtonList()); %>
```

...

I don't know what wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Both unity controller requests are created within the same HTTP request/reply, hence you get the same instance. You need to switch so that the controllers have a Transient lifetime.

I would switch to `DependencyResolver` instead of using `ControllerFactory` since you are running MVC3.

Comment: But the controller is set to Transient lifetime.
So, how can I set it to respond to more than one request for the same controller within the same HTTP request?

Thanks...

Comment: try switching to DependencyResolver, might be something with your controller factory.

Comment: I did that, but, I still get the same issue, maybe I need to check if the type is already registered then, I will skip the resolving for the same type again?

Comment: The error says that you should use a new controller for every resolution. Hence you should not check anything but return a new controller each time your container is invoked.